# "Range check error." on try change statusbar color with Delphi Alexandria 11.0(Android)

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-11-alexandria

i'm trying to change the statusbar color on my android app and always get this error "Range check error."

Already tried to do a blank application and the error persists.

My code is:

```
  TAndroidHelper.Activity.getWindow.setStatusBarColor($FF2ED573);
  TAndroidHelper.Activity.getWindow.setNavigationBarColor($FF34495E);
```

and my uses is

```
Androidapi.Helpers
```

I have a app that i build on 10.2 and just recompiled/deploy on 11.0 and works fine, the problem is on new apps.

Comment: Cast the literals to the type of the parameter of the two function calls

Comment: @DavidHeffernan that works! how dumb i'm on not trying that! Thanks for the help!